# How to declare an array of objects typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I apologise is the title isn't correctly worded, I'm fairly new to Programming.

I have an object, for this example lets say its the following

```
export default interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  }
```

I want to have a pre-set array of "Person" where I define the values myself. I'm trying it this way however I cant get the syntax quite right (or maybe I'm going about it the complete wrong way)

```
import Minion from './Minion';

    export default interface DefinedPeople {
        CategoryA: Person[
        {
            name: "Dave",
            age: 42
        },
        {
            type: "SomePerson",
            age: 50
        }],
        CategoryB: Person[
        {
            name: "Bob",
            age: 23
        }]
    }
```

I'm aware this may seem overcomplicated, however for what I'm trying to do it is necessary.

In the end I want to be able to have for example; `DefinedPeople.CategoryA[0].name` be "Dave"

Comment: Interfaces *do not exist at runtime*. You cannot have an interface with an array in it. If you want something concrete, you need a class. Interfaces only define what an object *looks like*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @VLAZ interfaces cannot be instantiated, they just prescribe a "shape" for a class implementing them. So in your example `DefinedPeople.CategoryA[0].name` doesn't make sense, because you cannot access the property `CategoryA` on an interface (which is not an object).

For the same reason you can't use your `Person` interface to initialise an instance variable like you're trying to do in `DefinedPeople`.

In order to get what you want, your `DefinedPeople` interface should look like this:

```
export default interface DefinedPeople {
    CategoryA: Person[]
    CategoryB: Person[]
 }
```

Then you can define a class implementing `DefinedPeople` and create an object from that class:

```
 export default class SomeClassWithDefinedPeople implements DefinedPeople {
       CategoryA = [
          {
             name: "Dave",
             age: 42
          },
          {
             type: "SomePerson",
             age: 50
          }],
      CategoryB = [
          {
             name: "Bob",
             age: 23
          }]
 }

const instance = new SomeClassWithDefinedPeople();
instance.CategoryA[0].name
```

Please note that in this case every new instance of `SomeClassWithDefinedPeople` will have the properties `CategoryA` and `CategoryB` initialited with the values declared in the class definition.

Or you can just create a single object of type `DefinedPeople`:

```
const instance: DefinedPeople = {
      CategoryA: [
           {
              name: "Dave",
              age: 42
           },
           {
              type: "SomePerson",
              age: 50
           }],
       CategoryB: [
           {
              name: "Bob",
              age: 23
           }]
    }
instance.CategoryA[0].name
```